# How to stop viewWillTransition on ResignActive

Tags: ios, swift, viewwilltransitiontosize

I have `UIViewController` with `CollectionView` and other buttons on the screen and using `viewWillTransition` when rotate the device. My problem is that when I minimize the application, and later open it again with the same rotation, it always go through `viewWillTransition` again. How can I disable it? I want to use the implementation only on orientation changed.

Comment: Just a thought, but could you (1) override it but (2) only call `super` when you want to transition?

Comment: How can I do that? And I'm searching for nicer way.

Comment: Is this an iOS app? You've tagged it as that but you also talk of "minimizing the app". If it is, look at the various events/functions in `AppDelegate`. Choose among them, and maintain a `UserDefault` variable to indicate the current state of your app (launching, entering background/foreground, etc.). Then in your `viewWillTransition` override, use that flag to decide what to do (or not do). It may not be the *most elegant* way, but it is a *clear* way to accomplish this.

Comment: This is what I already did, I have sharedInstance(DeviceUtils) and use a flag, but this is not so clean way..